# What is a .dom extension?

Tags: domains, dns, intranet

I have been asked to use a `.dom` extension for an intranet service that I'm working on. I used to think that it was a mistake but the client says it's not.

Can you explain what is a `.dom` domain and how to use it?

Comment: Looks like it's been [registered](http://inaic.com/index.php?p=news-21-05-2015) but I can't find anything past that.

Comment: "for an intranet" - on an intranet you can use anything you like, but it's probably a mistake to do so, as you can end up with potential conflicts.

Comment: @AndrewLott It is because you are not looking in the official sources. If you look at https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db you will see that as of today `.DOM` is not an existing TLD in IANA root zone, hence it basically does not exist on the Internet as everyone uses this root zone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know a `.com`? Well that, but now it says `.dom`. You just think it's weird because you've heard `.com` a lot which makes it sound normal, but on a technical level, they're similar.

There used to be only a few extentions, but now you can have almost anything you want (e.g. if you have enough money, you can do `www.example.ferdinand`).

Internal servers are even easier, it doesn't have to be an existing extention, just set up your internal server to understand that `example.dom` is as much a domain as `example.com`, or as the commonly used `example.test` in a development setting.

Comment: It is a very bad advice to give. Do not use blindly a TLD to name your internal resources. You will suffer a lot in case of collisions, and it already happened with `.dev`. Instead register a domain name, say `mycompany.example` (in a true existing TLD) and use it as base to name your internal resources like `int.mycompany.example`, etc.